# Can AWS CLI be used with a federated login?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, federated-identity

I login to AWS with my Active Directory account in my company. We are using federated login, as described [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/introduction_access-management.html):

> Federated Users and Roles
>
> Federated users don't have permanent identities in your AWS account the way that IAM users do. To assign permissions to federated users, you can create an entity referred to as a role and define permissions for the role. When a federated user signs in to AWS, the user is associated with the role and is granted the permissions that are defined in the role. For more information, see Creating a Role for a Third-Party Identity Provider (Federation).

My company has a Security Token Service (STS) which is a SAML provider.

I can use that to login to AWS management console, but can I login to AWS CLI as well with my federated login?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, however it's not straight forward. There is a rather long blog post in the AWS Security Blog explaining how to be able to use the CLI as SAML-federated user: https://aws.amazon.com/de/blogs/security/how-to-implement-federated-api-and-cli-access-using-saml-2-0-and-ad-fs/

Comment: I've read that before, but I thought it's geared towards the people who implement the federated user, not people who use it.

Answer (score 9):

saml2aws can be used for AWS CLI for the federated user.

Refer https://github.com/Versent/saml2aws this is based on python code from https://aws.amazon.com/de/blogs/security/how-to-implement-federated-api-and-cli-access-using-saml-2-0-and-ad-fs/

You can use the below command to login to default IDP AWS account, your organization will provide you the IDP account name.

```
saml2aws --idp-account="default" --username=USERNAME --password=PASSWORD
```

For using the federated user for automation, you need to use `exec`

```
saml2aws --idp-account="default" --username=USERNAME --password=PASSWORD exec command
```

Comment: This works great for Google Workspace (aka Apps) federated accounts, using the method for getting the SSO URL here: https://github.com/Versent/saml2aws/issues/493#issuecomment-1093136800

Answer (score 2):

Here are sample steps to configure for federated users.

```sh
$ aws configure sso    
SSO session name (Recommended): my-sso
SSO start URL [None]: https://my-sso-portal.awsapps.com/start
SSO region [None]: us-east-1
SSO registration scopes [None]: sso:account:access
```

Source: [Configure automatic token refresh](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/sso-configure-profile-token.html)

Comment: How does one find their SSO Start URL? The redirect url I use to login manually to AWS Console is not the right format

Comment: @geominded as a federated user, I've gotten mine from my admin. it's something like https://d-xxxxxxxxxx.awsapps.com/start or https://somecustomnames.awsapps.com/start

Answer (score 0):

you can create your AWS Accesskey, Secret key & token for the federated users
using [AssumeRoleWithSAML-cli](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/sts/assume-role-with-saml.html)

AWS CLI Example that will provide you an credentials for federated user:

> aws sts assume-role-with-saml --role-arn
> arn:aws:iam::AccountNumber:role/ADFS-AWS-ADMIN --principal-arn
> arn:aws:iam::AccountNumber:saml-provider/idp001 --saml-assertion
> 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